# очень долго работает программа C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

При нажатии на кнопку требуется, чтобы различия в Dateidaten1 и Dateidaten2 (это RichTexBox) закрасились. При работе с небольшими данными все работает отлично, при работе с большими данными программа зависает на очень долго. Пытался сделать с помощью потоков, но в итоге программа даже с маленькими данными зависала) Помогите, пожалуйста

```
private: System::Void compare_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    int textLength = Math::Min(Dateidaten1->Text->Length, Dateidaten2->Text->Length);

    Dateidaten1->SuspendLayout();
    Dateidaten2->SuspendLayout();

    for (int i = 0; i < textLength; i++)
    {
        if (Dateidaten1->Text[i] != Dateidaten2->Text[i])
        {
            Dateidaten1->SelectionStart = i;
            Dateidaten1->SelectionLength = 1;
            Dateidaten1->SelectionColor = Color::Red;
            Dateidaten2->SelectionStart = i;
            Dateidaten2->SelectionLength = 1;
            Dateidaten2->SelectionColor = Color::Red;
        }
    }
    Dateidaten1->ResumeLayout();
    Dateidaten2->ResumeLayout();
}
```

Comment: На C++/CLI приложения не пишут. Dixi. Поэтому вам никто не поможет. Никто!

Comment: Layout - это расположение _контролов_. К раскраске текста отношения не имеет. Поэтому включать/выключать его смысла нет.

Comment: Красить по одному символу - естественно, будет медленно. Находите совпадающую строку и красьте сразу её за один раз.

Comment: RichTextBox для таких операций не пригоден. Возьмите какой-нибудь другой контрол для работы с текстом. Например, FastColoredTextBox или Scintilla.